# How to use a post_save receiver with django-polymorphic?

Tags: python, django, polymorphism

I have a  `django-polymorphic` model and want to implement a `post_save` signal to automatically create a related model that is also polymorphic.

It's something like the code below, the relevant piece of non-working code being the `@receiver` decorated `work_post_save` method. The problem is the instance is a ctype_id and not an object.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

from mygallery.models import Album

# Work Parent PolymorphicModel
class Work(PolymorphicModel):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256)

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Work)
def work_post_save(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    album, new = Album.objects.get_or_create(title=instance.title + ' Stills', slug=instance.slug + '-stills')
    work_album, new = WorkAlbum.objects.get_or_create(work=instance, album=album, is_key=True)


class ArtProject(Work):
    manifesto = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=256)

class CodeProject(Work):
    code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=256)


# Content Parent PolymorphicModel
class WorkContent(PolymorphicModel):
    is_key = models.BooleanField(default=False, unique=True, default=False)


class WorkAlbum(WorkContent):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, related_name='work_albums')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='album_works')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've only fiddled around with this for a bit so I'm not 100% sure what the correct way of handling this is.

What I ended up doing is to **not** declaring the `sender` in the `@receiver` annotation. This has the effect that the callback is triggered by every `post_save` signal. Then in the callback I check `isinstance()` with my parent model (in your case `Work`), so that the callback is only executed after a model I'm interested in is saved. When the callback is executed, the `instance` parameter is a child model (in your case `ArtProject` or `CodeProject`).

```
@receiver(signals.post_save)
def work_post_save(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, Work):
        # instance is either ArtProject or CodeProject
        album, new = Album.objects.get_or_create(title=instance.title + ' Stills', slug=instance.slug + '-stills')
        work_album, new = WorkAlbum.objects.get_or_create(work=instance, album=album, is_key=True)
```

Triggering directly on the parent `save()` is apparently [not supported](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318).